# git error: This operation must be run in a work tree

Tags: git, netbeans

I have a repository on bitbucket that I would like to import into a .git folder I have created on my live shared host web server ( where I have git installed ). I can give commands via SSH. I am following the instructions in http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

I have been able to set up the 2 repos on the server as described in the article. I also have the post update and post commit hooks in place. I am trying to test the system by pushing an update to the server. I am using netbeans 7.3 beta git support. However when give the command:

```
push ( in netbeans ) to ssh://****.com/home/******/site_hub.git

==[IDE]== Nov 19, 2012 10:28:15 PM Pushing
git push ssh://***.com/home/***/site_hub.git +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Repository Updates
Branch : master
Old Id : 0121897bdd7cf3caad9e18717fc27a7a08***
New Id : 837c194c70fb41dc7de3be7841c946ca***
Result : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

Local Repository Updates
No update
==[IDE]== Nov 19, 2012 10:28:18 PM Pushing finished.
```

I was advised to try " git pull in order to merge both branches, and then push the result" - this did not work.

I was also advised to try " git fetch and then a git rebase origin/master (or whatever names you put to your remote and HEAD branch) so your commits are applied on top of the remote branch. Then you can push the result "

Can anyone advise me on what to do next?

Can this be done in netbeans or do I need to go to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/#website. I couldn't get it done in netbeans but used the git gui  instead- Regards, Bill